# How do you disable SMB printing support?

Tags: centos, logging, server-message-block, cups

I'm running CentOS on a storage server that has to do file sharing for with Windows machines. SMB version is `smbd version 3.5.5-68.fc13`

I'm getting a lot of error messages in /var/log/messages regarding failed attempts to connect to a CUPS server. They look like this:

```
Nov 30 18:49:34 big03 smbd[9927]: [2010/11/30 18:49:34.850620,  0] printing/print_cups.c:108(cups_connect)
Nov 30 18:49:34 big03 smbd[9927]:   Unable to connect to CUPS server localhost:631 - Connection refused
```

I understand that the issue is generated by the fact that SMB comes with printer sharing support, but I'm really not interested in that. I just want to disable the feature to get rid of the messages.

Any idea how I can do that?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Commenting out the printers section actually does nothing, add this to your smb.conf in the [global] section:

```
load printers = no
printing = bsd
printcap name = /dev/null
disable spoolss = yes
```

(spoolss is not a typo)

Comment: These directives have to be added to `[global]` section. Just to be sure...

Comment: Why do we set the printing protocol do bsd and settings the spoolss?

Answer (score 1):

Becareful about missing network interfaces referenced in Samba config file!
Put:
log level = 2
into cinfig file, restart Samba and check log entries.
Worked for me ;-)